# Crystal Error Messages: Boolean and Number

Tags: crystal-reports, syntax-error

I get a message that a Boolean is expected and when replacing `0` with `TRUE`/`FALSE` I get a message that a number is required.

below is code :

```
If NumericText({myfield}) Then 
    ToNumber(myfield})
Else
    0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The formula looks OK, except the missing curly bracket here: `ToNumber(myfield})` But I guess this is a typo? What data type is `{myfield}`?

Answer (score 0):

your field equals ??

If NumericText({myfield}) ***??*** Then ToNumber(myfield}) Else 0

Comment: The `NumericText()`-method returns a Boolean so there's nothing missing in the formula except the curly brace...